# Read Xls file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a simple javacript function which can store data from xls files  in an array. My code is as below but it returns nothing can anybody help me?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script>
function GetData(){ 
          var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
          var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\testyt.xls"); 
          var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet2"); 
          for(var i=2;i<20;i++){
            var myrow = excel_sheet.Range("A"+i);    //to read values in row A
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = myrow; 
          }
}
</script>
 
 
 
 
 <body>
 
 
<form id="From1" method="post">
   <div1 id="div1">
<h2></h2>
   </div1>
<p style="font-size:150%;margin-left:200px; margin-top:60px">Read Data </p>
<input type="button"   onclick="GetData();"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless you are using IE (which is basically now deprecated) there is no hope of this working as written. What errors do you see in the developer tools console when you try to run it?

Comment: I amusing IE only but still it is not working can u give me any other link for the tutorial for same?

Comment: see the answer provided by TJ Crowder below which should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The only browser that supported ActiveX was IE, and only with very permissive security settings. IE Edge drops ActiveX entirely.

That mean you can't use `ActiveXObject` anymore unless you're targeting IE11 and earlier on an intranet. You'll either need to do your processing on a server, or use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to read the raw xls data and process it in the browser (not trivial!).

---

In an IE-only intranet environment using up to IE11, with your security settings tuned to allow ActiveX in the Intranet Zone, the ActiveX part might work, but you have a bug in your code. You have this line in the loop:

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = myrow;
```

...which means that you'll fill in that div with the content of row 2, then overwrite it with the content of row 3, then ovewrite *that* with the content of row 4, etc.

If you want the content of all rows, you'll want multiple divs or similar:

```
document.getElementById('div' + i).innerHTML = myrow;
```

(Assumes divs with `id`s like `div2` through `div22`.)

Also note that if you're not going to use jQuery, you could not include it; or you could continue to include it, and then *use* it: `$("#div" + i).html(myrow);`